# Error when opening a minimal Unity WebGL game on itch.io

Tags: unity, webgl, publishing

I created a very simple game in Unity 2020, built it to WebGL, and uploaded it to [itch.io](https://erelsgl.itch.io/personship). When I open the game, I see the following error:

```
"InvalidStateError: A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations"
```

[image]

When I do "Build and run" from Unity, the game runs with no errors.
How can I fix this error?

EDIT: Here is the content of the browser error console:

```
[UnityCache] 'https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/html/4671392/Spaceship/Build/Spaceship.data.gz' successfully downloaded but not stored in the indexedDB cache due to the error: [object Event] Spaceship.loader.js:1:7539
Loading player data from data.unity3d
Spaceship.framework.js.gz:2:44302
Initialize engine version: 2020.3.9f1 (108be757e447)
Spaceship.framework.js.gz:2:44302
Creating WebGL 2.0 context. Spaceship.loader.js:1:4492
Renderer: Mozilla
Spaceship.framework.js.gz:2:44302
Vendor:   Mozilla
Spaceship.framework.js.gz:2:44302
Version:  OpenGL ES 3.0 (WebGL 2.0)
Spaceship.framework.js.gz:2:44302
GLES:     3
Spaceship.framework.js.gz:2:44302
 EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_float EXT_float_blend GL_EXT_float_blend EXT_texture_compression_bptc GL_EXT_texture_compression_bptc EXT_texture_compression_rgtc GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_texture_float_linear OVR_multiview2 GL_OVR_multiview2 WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc GL_WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc_srgb GL_WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc_srgb WEBGL_debug_renderer_info GL_WEBGL_debug_renderer_info WEBGL_debug_shaders GL_WEBGL_debug_shaders WEBGL_lose_context GL_WEBGL_lose_context
Spaceship.framework.js.gz:2:44302
OPENGL LOG: Creating OpenGL ES 3.0 graphics device ; Context level  <OpenGL ES 3.0> ; Context handle 23010984
Spaceship.framework.js.gz:2:44302
UnloadTime: 1.000000 ms
Spaceship.framework.js.gz:2:44302
Invoking error handler due to
InvalidStateError: A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations.
storeRemoteEntry@https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/html/4671392/Spaceship/Build/Spaceship.framework.js.gz:2:79149
reconcile/</<@https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/html/4671392/Spaceship/Build/Spaceship.framework.js.gz:2:80515
loadLocalEntry@https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/html/4671392/Spaceship/Build/Spaceship.framework.js.gz:2:78006
reconcile/<@https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/html/4671392/Spaceship/Build/Spaceship.framework.js.gz:2:80444
reconcile@https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/html/4671392/Spaceship/Build/Spaceship.framework.js.gz:2:80266
syncfs/</<@https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/html/4671392/Spaceship/Build/Spaceship.framework.js.gz:2:75836
@https://v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net/html/4671392/Spaceship/Build/Spaceship.framework.js.gz:2:77665
```

Comment: Can you run the WebGL build locally without uploading it to a website?

Comment: Apparently, this error can come up when you run something in Firefox private windows.

Comment: @Vaillancourt I do run it in Firefox, but in a usual window - not a private window.